# Dynamically Allocated mpfr_t matrix with std::vector

Tags: c++, stl, gmp, mpfr

I want to have a class that works as a matrix of mpfr_t elements. I thought STL Vectors would be a great idea for dynamically allocating as many of these as I want, but I get some errors here.

```
#ifndef GMPMATRIX_H
#define GMPMATRIX_H

#include <vector>
#include <mpfr.h>

typedef std::vector<mpfr_t> mpVector;
typedef std::vector<mpVector> mpMatrix;

class GmpMatrix
{
    private:
        int n;
        int m;
        mpMatrix elements;

    public:
        GmpMatrix() {}
        GmpMatrix(int n, int m)
        {
            this->n = n;
            this->m = m;

            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            {
                mpVector e_push(m);
                for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
                {
                    mpfr_t e;
                    mpfr_init(e);
                    e_push.push_back(e);
                }
            }
        }


        ~GmpMatrix() {}
};

#endif // GMPMATRIX_H
```

The errors are:

```
   /usr/include/c++/5/ext/new_allocator.h:120:4: error: parenthesized initializer in array new [-fpermissive]
      { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
        ^
    /usr/include/c++/5/ext/new_allocator.h:120:4: error: no matching function for call to ‘__mpfr_struct::__mpfr_struct(const __mpfr_struct [1])’
```

I've really looked into this and I can't figure it out. Is there a way to make a `vector< vector<mpfr_t> >` work? Does anyone know what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mpfr_t` is a C-style array type. You cannot store those in `std::vector`.

You can wrap `mpfr_t` in a simple `struct`  and store those.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This compiles using your wrapper.